# Regex pattern for checking if a string starts with ], a letter and a number

Tags: c#, regex

I'm developing a library with .NET Framework 4.0 and C#.

I want to check if a string begins with this three caracters:

- ]
- One letter (any)
- One number (any)

An example: `]d2`

How can I do it using regex?

Comment: It's important to state whether or not the order of the characters is relevant or not.

Comment: Maybe you could [teach yourself regular expressions in general](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and don't telling why.

Comment: @VansFannel you will get downvotes and flags because... "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." As its stands, it's off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex matches such a string

```
^\][a-zA-Z][0-9]
```

- `^` matches start of string
- `]` is a special character in regex and needs to be escaped
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches any letter (any case)
- `[0-9]` matches a digit. This can be replaced with `\d`. It is worth noting that `\d` matches digits other than 0 to 9 (like Unicode values corresponding to numerals in other languages)

Answer (score 3):

- `^` - beginning of line
- `\]` - the literal character, "]"
- `[a-zA-Z]` - one letter, a-z, lower or uppercase
- `\d` - one digit

All together: `^\][a-zA-Z]\d`

I might be slightly off if .NET 4.0 C# regexes aren't exactly as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the code would be:

```
var result = Regex.Match("]d2", @"^\][a-zA-Z][0-9].*");
```